# Traduction de « overlay »

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

Je suis en train de rédiger un document à propos d'une page web contenant divers boutons faisant apparaître des pop-ups avec un overlay. Mais j'aimerais ne pas utiliser d'anglicismes.

J'ai pensé à :

> un panneau qui recouvre la page en cours

Mais je trouve cela peu clair, même si je pense que ça reste une bonne définition.

Comment: A noter que de mon côté j'ai déjà eu plusieurs fois des malentendus avec l'utilisation du terme popup. En ce qui me concerne un popup est une nouvelle fenêtre de navigateur, généralement sans les boutons de navigation, mais c'est de moins en moins utilisé vu que le principe a été abusé pour finalement être bloqué par défaut par les navigateurs. J'essaie donc d'éduquer mes interlocuteurs afin d'employer une terminologie plus claire : popup pour un popup, lightbox (fenêtre modale) pour une lightbox.

Comment: Parlez-vous de ces fenêtres modales qui proposent des vidéos youtube dès que j'ouvre firefox ? Youtube est intrusif ou le coupable est-il autre chose ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR

Si j'ai bien compris ce que l'on cherche à décrire, il s'agit d'une **fenêtre modale** avec un **voile** devant le reste de l'application.

## Pop-up

La [remarque de cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14762/7224) concernant *pop-up* est pertinente : ce terme est compris en français. [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-up) propose également **fenêtre intruse**<sup>1</sup> ou **fenêtre surgissante**.

La terminologie *fenêtre intruse* a été recommandée (voire note 1) mais je pense qu'elle ne s'applique que dans le cas où la fenêtre n'a pas été sollicitée par l'utilisateur.

On peut aussi penser à une **[fenêtre modale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fen%C3%AAtre_modale)**, mais celle-ci implique généralement que le reste de l'application n'est pas accessible tant que la modale n'est pas fermée (cf. plus bas).

## Overlay

Sans plus de précision, ce terme est très vague. Il peut aussi bien désigner les badges qui s'appliquent sur certaines icônes (celles de raccourcis, par exemple) dans le monde Linux qu'effectivement des panneaux. Je vais rester sur cette approche puisque c'est celle avancée par la question.

En relisant la question et [la proposition de CitronEvanescent](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14763/7224), je pense que le mot **voile** peut rendre l'idée comme tu l'espères : un voile recouvre la page ; on la voit toujours, mais on ne peut interagir avec elle.

## Modalité ?

Si, comme je le comprends, il ne s'agit pas d'une nouvelle fenêtre de navigateur mais plutôt d'une « fenêtre » à l'intérieur de la page web, et que le but de l'*overlay* est d'empêcher l'accès au reste de la page tant que la « pop-up » n'est pas fermée, alors ***fenêtre modale* est la terminologie consacrée**.

Pour exemple, voici un exemple de fenêtre modale dans le framework [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

[image: Fenêtre modale dans Bootstrap]

---

<sub>**Note sans rapport direct avec la question**</sub>

<sub>Selon le type de document que l'on rédige, le niveau de détail à fournir n'est pas le même. Dans des spécifications techniques, on se contentera généralement de préciser que le reste de l'application n'est pas accessible tant que la modale est ouverte (ce qui est redondant avec l'aspect modal de la fenêtre).</sub>

<sub>Si on tient à préciser le rendu, on peut évoquer l'idée de *voile* (c'est ce qui me semble le plus approprié), mais une image est souvent plus simple que de longs discours. Pour décrire rapidement une interface à créer, je conseille de s'appuyer sur des *wireframes* (que l'on peut créer avec des outils tels que Balsamiq, Mockingbird et les nombreuses alternatives qui existent, mais ceci est [un sujet pour Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=wireframe)).</sub>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> [Terme recommandé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommandation_(terminologie)) par la [DGLFLF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/DGLFLF), journal officiel du 18/12/2005, voir [FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=pop-up&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) [[archive](http://archive.wikiwix.com/cache/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.culture.fr%2Ffranceterme%2Fresult%3FfrancetermeSearchTerme%3Dpop-up%26francetermeSearchDomaine%3D0%26francetermeSearchSubmit%3Drechercher%26action%3Dsearch)]</sub>

Comment: En anglais ca se nomme *lightbox*, et je crois aussi que c'est ce que l'OP recherche.

Comment: @LaurentS. La traduction anglaise de « fenêtre modale » est bien plus mot-à-mot : il s'agit de « [_Modal window_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) ». [Lightbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)) est une bibliothèque JavaScript utilisant effectivement ces principes en combinaison avec des animations pour l'affichage notamment d'images et de vidéos.

Comment: > C'est AUSSI une bibliothèque, mais c'est un terme assez générique. Cfr par exemple [cet article](http://www.blogduwebdesign.com/ressources-javascript/14-Light-box-pour-mettre-vos-images-en-avant/1493) décrivant 14 framworks ayant le même effet. Concrètement, une lightbox est tout le temps une fenêtre modale dans le sens où le reste du site n'est pas vraiment accessible (cliquable) tant qu'elle est ouverte. Une fenêtre modale n'est pas nécessairement une lightbox par contre... La plupart des logicels utilisent de telles fenêtres.

Comment: @LaurentS. J'imagine que c'est un abus de langage pour désigner l'effet popularisé par cette bibliothèque (il me semble que c'était la première à le mettre en œuvre). Merci pour le lien. (« La plupart des logiciels » : web, je suppose ? Je ne me souviens pas encore avoir rencontré l'effet Lightbox dans des clients sur PC.)

Comment: > D'aussi loin que je me souvienne, j'ai toujours entendu ce terme pour décrire cela (je suis en Belgique et nous sommes peu moins enclins à trouver une traduction francophone à tous les termes). De plus il me semble assez approprié pour être générique : généralement la fenêtre en question est plus lumineuse, le fond du site étant partiellement occulté. Il n'y a malheureusement à ma connaissance aucune traduction mot-à-mot du terme...

Answer (score 6):

> Un panneau vient *se superposer à* la page active.

---

- <sup>On peut emploier aussi *'une pop-up'* pour panneau, c'est un anglicisme compris par tous, en revanche *overlay* n'est connu que des informaticiens.</sup>
- <sup>Contrairement à ce que l'on pourrait penser, alors qu'on pose un objet *sur* quelque chose, on superpose un objet *à* quelque chose.</sup>

Comment: Bien trouvé, je trouve, car ces panneaux/pop-ups « superposants » sont  super imposants (sens immisçant) mais  loin d’être super reposants !

Answer (score 0):

Dans le dictionnaire, on mentionne que la traduction version informatique est [recouvrement](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/overlay/599698).

Comment: J'ai bien lu les définitions trouvées sur internet, mais je les trouve peu claires et encore moins explicites.

Comment: Dans ton document, insère une note de bas de page avec la définition. C'est le meilleur moyen de faire selon moi.

Answer (score 0):

Si je devais absolument le traduire je dirais plutôt un "cache" ou un "rideau" (opaque / transparent / translucide) pour préciser à quoi il ressemble.